# Correct usage of smart pointers and programming style

Tags: c++, c++11

Is this a correct way of thinking about smart pointers and using raw pointers for non-ownership?

```
class DisplayObject {
    DisplayObject* Parent;
};

class DisplayObjectContainer: public DisplayObject {
    std::vector<DisplayObject*> Children;
};

class Stage {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DisplayObject>> DisplayObjects;
};
```

Items are created using
`make_unique<DisplayObject>`
or
`make_unique<DisplayObjectContainer>`

Stage would own all `DisplayObject` classes but a `DisplayObjectContainer` will have raw pointers to Stage's owned objects.

`DisplayObject` will also have a Parent (which can be `nullptr`).

I also take the Stage's DisplayObjects and get the pointer to it's object when I add the item to the vector (`DisplayObjects.back().get()`) and make heavy use of `std::move`

Is this a correct way of using smart pointers and ownership?

Comment: Instead of `&*DisplayObjects.back()`, you can use `DisplayObjects.back().get()`, which is more cleaner

Comment: @balki Sorry, that's what I actually use :) Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code, yes. This looks like a perfectly good way to organize your code: you have a single class which is keeping explicit ownership, and every other class that uses raw pointers does not own what it is pointing at. This will keep your code clean, efficient, and everybody using it will know what breaks when, and how.

Just make sure if you do start to share this code around, you tell everyone upfront that raw pointers means it doesn't own resources, and that they are to not delete or new the resources themselves. Making this known upfront will prevent confusion on whether or not the pointers people use / pass to your methods need to be manually new'd.

***Side note:***

`DisplayObject`? `DisplayObjectContainer`? Sounds a lot like [AS3's display hierarchy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) for C++! It sounds interesting. I wish you all the best.

Comment: I used AS3's display hierarchy as it fits my example :)